# Detecting weekends in SQL query for Access database

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I have an MS Access database, in which the records of a table have a *text* field that stores dates in the form 29-Mar-14 (as text). I know, this is not a good database design, but this is how my client's database system was originally developed and I cannot modify it.

My questions is: How do I run an SQL Update command on this table, to be applied only on weekend records? So basically I need help in 2 points:

- On how to write the SQL statement so that it treats the text fields of "29-Mar-14" as dates, and
- On how to write the SQL Update statement so that it detects which dates are weekends.

Thanks!

Comment: Great place to start is using the datepart fucntion.  See this: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1119279-149-1.aspx

Comment: `SELECT CDATE(fieldName,'DD-MON-YY')` then use a `weekday` function  without specific table names, field names, sample data and what you're wanting to update... I'm not sure what else to provide.  thus a comment not an answer.

Comment: Here's a copy of the database with just one record in: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/30638883/db.mdb

Comment: @KrisGruttemeyer `DatePart()` in Access SQL does not work the same way as `DATEPART()` in T-SQL.

Comment: @xQbert `CDate()` in Access SQL does not work that way.

Comment: so I guess the update command should be something like: UPDATE [newspapers] SET round_name = 'whatever' WHERE CDATE(delivery_date,'DD-MON-YY'); ... but what is the correct syntax for CDATE in Access, and how do I make this for weekends-only?

Answer (score 0):

The challenge here is that the `CDate()` function in Access will interpret '29-Mar-14' as 2029-03-14. So, you need to swap the day and year

```
CDate(Right(delivery_date,2) & "-" & Mid(delivery_date,4,3) & "-" & Left(delivery_Date,2))
```

The above will give you the true Date value. To determine if it is a weekend date, pass that date value to the [Weekday()](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/access-help/weekday-function-HA001228933.aspx) function and see if it returns 1 (`vbSunday`) or 7 (`vbSaturday`).

Comment: I still don't get the expected results. I run the following query: SELECT * FROM newspapers WHERE weekday(CDate(Right(delivery_date,2) & "-" & Mid(delivery_date,4,3) & "-" & Left(delivery_Date,2)))=1; and I get results with delivery dates "04-Mar-14" and "10-Mar-14" (a Tuesday and a Monday).

Comment: Ok, here's the query that worked on my system: SELECT * FROM newspapers WHERE weekday(CDate(delivery_date))=1; (this selects sundays). Thanks to everyone for their contribution.